# How to find transfer value in internal transaction by go ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, internal-transactions

1. How can I know how much ether is transfer to the receiver such as `0xa1ca8da0496cFA2f8579F58db30AE8aD8dbe6F0C`?
2. Is its method id `0x2da91fa2` important?

I found the transaction in [EtherScan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9aca88a62adb439fd737f43a6e8f3ddee27e124a9e4bb42f95f2a8db1198e5a4), its hash is `0x9aca88a62adb439fd737f43a6e8f3ddee27e124a9e4bb42f95f2a8db1198e5a4`, and block height is 4371625.

I can find the addresses of receiver in input data, such as `0000000000000000000000006008767265b0060733884b59768ded777cf0930b` and `000000000000000000000000a1ca8da0496cfa2f8579f58db30ae8ad8dbe6f0c`. And the method id is `0x2da91fa2`.

I cannot find the *2.019 Ether* in input data, but EtherScan can display that *TRANSFER  2.019 Ether  to `0xa1ca8da0496cFA2f8579F58db30AE8aD8dbe6F0C`*.

I am developing an Android wallet application by `go-ethereum` in light client mode. User can see the list of send/receive Ether when pressing ETH button.